# How to disable Address Book Server in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, contacts, carddav

I have a huge `error.log` file in `/private/var/log/carddavd` folder. I found out that the Address Book Server creates logs in this folder.

Can anyone suggest me a way to disable the Address Book Server so I don't have to worry about these log files in the future?

Edit - the issue is only with OSX Servers.

Comment: I don't have a carddav account added to my address book and don't have this folder. Maybe simply disabling the specific carddav account solves your problem?

Comment: Are you running stock OS X or the Server additions also?

Comment: Updated question.